# How are the dimensions of PopupMenu widget determined by Android?

Tags: android, popupmenu

It's known that PopupMenu is pretty impervious to customization, so I'm switching one of my PopupMenus to a ListWindowMenu. The latter allows you to use your own adapter and layouts.

My problem is I need to recreate the size of the PopupMenu, but I'm not sure how to retrieve it. There is no layout defined, and it seems to size itself somehow. I took a look into PopupMenu, and Menu, but I could not find how they size themselves and how I can get dimensions.

Does anyone know 
1) How to get dimensions of a popupmenu
2) How are these android widgets sizing themselves?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`PopupMenu` in low level actually is an `ListPopupWindow`, which contains `DropDownListView`.

`DropDownListView` is an child of `ListView`, so he has an **Adapter**.

As you know each adapter have `getView()` method, which inflated resource to show up each item.

So, for you answer is an :

```
height = com.android.internal.R.layout.popup_menu_item_layout * items_count.
width = dynamically measured value but it can not be bigger than :
```

> Math.max(res.getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels / 2,       res.getDimensionPixelSize(com.android.internal.R.dimen.config_prefDialogWidth));

Measure logic you can see [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.0.0_r1/android/widget/ListView.java#ListView.measureHeightOfChildren%28int%2Cint%2Cint%2Cint%2Cint%29).